# Notations in Functional Analysis: $L^p$, $L_p$, $\mathscr{L}^p$, $\mathscr{L}_p$, $\mathcal{L}^p$, and $\mathcal{L}_p$

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, notation, definition, lp-spaces

If my memory doesn't fail me, then to some functional analysts, $L^p$ and $L_p$ spaces are two different things.  I understand that many people use $L_p$ to means the space of functions with finite $p$-norm (i.e, $p^\text{th}$-power-integrable functions), while other use the notation $L^p$ for the same purpose.  If you are a functional analyst that distinguishes between $L^p$ and $L_p$, then could you please let me know what $L_p$ means (presumably, your definition of $L^p$ coincides with [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space))?

Now, I found another similar notation $\mathscr{L}_p$.  What is $\mathscr{L}_p$?  There seem to be $\mathscr{L}^p$, $\mathcal{L}^p$, and $\mathcal{L}_p$ too.  However, I would expect that this is just due to people's using different fonts, i.e., $L^p=\mathscr{L}^p=\mathcal{L}^p$ and $L_p=\mathscr{L}_p=\mathcal{L}_p$.

Comment: I have seen $L_p$ being used as the space containing actual functions with finite $\Vert \cdot\Vert_p-$norm, as opposed to  $L^p$ being the space of a.e.-equivalence classes of such functions. But I don't know how common this is.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of the distinction between $L_p$ spaces and $\mathscr L_p$ spaces.

Comment: @RobertIsrael  What are $L_p$ and $\mathscr{L}_p$ in you case?  (It is difficult to do a Google search on this, when Google recognizes any "Lp space" as "$L^p$ space" and nothing else.)

Comment: I learned it like this (from Dirk Werner personally :) )... $\mathscr L^p$ denotes the space of functions with finite $||\,\cdot\,||_p$-semi norm and $L^p$ is the space of equivalence classes $f \sim g$ if $f=g$ almost everywhere. The classes are such that $||\,\cdot\,||_p$ becomes a norm. I don't think it makes any sence to have more than two different symbols.

Answer (score 1):

The notation "some kind of L" with p "somwhere next to it" is so overused. It can mean:

1. The space of measurable functions on some [measure space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_space) with finite $p$ semi-norm. These objects are rarely used on their own. Usually they are a prelimiary steps for constructing Lebesgue spaces.
2. The [Lebesgue spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces_and_Lebesgue_integrals). They are a quotient of the former spaces by subspaces of functions with zero $p$ semi-norm. In case of [counting measre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure) we use special notation: $\ell_p$.
3. The Lindenstrauss-Pelczynski spaces. These space on a finite dimensional level level look just like finite dimensional $\ell_p$ spaces. See [Absolutely summing operators in Lp-spaces and their applications
   J. Lindenstrauss; A. Pełczyński, Studia Mathematica (1968)](https://eudml.org/doc/217232)
4. The non-commutative Lebesgue space constructed for a given [von Neumann algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra) and a [weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra#Weights.2C_states.2C_and_traces). This is a far reaching generalization, where you replace ordinary functions with bounded linear operators. See [Non-Commutative Lp-Spaces
   G. Pisier, Quanhua Xu](https://dmitripavlov.org/scans/pisier-xu.pdf)
5. ...

This is not a complete list since there are so many ways to generalize classical Lebesgue spaces. Always check the definition used by your book or article.